# adding lines of code to make the ball reverse direction at x = + 9 and x = - 9

Tags: python-2.7

This is simple but I cant get it.

```
from visual import *

ball = sphere (pos=(-4, 0, 0 ), radius=0.6, color=color.red)
ball.velocity = vector (15, 0, 0)
deltat = 0.005
t = 0
scene.autoscale = 0
while t < 4 :
 rate (100)
 ball.pos = ball.pos + ball.velocity*deltat
 t = t + deltat
```

from here I'm supposed to add lines to make the ball change direction at x=9 and x=-9. I'm not sure what im doing wrong

Comment: what do you mean by x in this code

Comment: Where in your code do you reverse the ball's velocity?

Comment: i havent reversed it yet, and x in this code means the x coordinate position .

Comment: So "I'm not sure what im doing wrong" actually means you haven't done it yet and you don't know how.

Comment: have you tried to get x coordinate and apply simple equation `if x % 9 == 0:`

Comment: no ive tried from visual import *
if ball.pos.x = -9 :
     ball.velocity = -ball.velocity
 if ball.pos.x = 9 :
     ball.velocity= -ball.velocity

Comment: but this was wrong

Comment: debug pos.x may it greater than -9 or 9 and modify your question with these lines of code

Comment: okay thank you ill try